# Transaction simulation failed: This account may not be used to pay transaction fees using Solana CLI

Tags: anchor, pda, solana-cli, transfer

I am getting this error using "solana transfer" at the command line.  "solana address," and "solana balance" both work fine, so it seems like the wallet is properly connected.

the error is as follows:

```
Error: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: This account may not be used to pay transaction fees
```

The address I am using was used as a seed in "findProgramAddressSync" for a creating an off curve PDA address.

There is nothing else particularly interesting about the account.  I am trying to zero it.

Comment: Check the owner of your provider wallet(the wallet that signs and pays for the transaction). If it's not the system program then that might be the issue

Comment: are you using the PDA to sign the tx or creating a PDA ?

Comment: I ended up resolving this.  I had to use a CPI to close the wallet.  The address was not owned by the system program.